# iOS Swift Value from [String : AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the value out of an [String : AnyObject] and have not yet found the answer on a web-reference

One of the parameters in a method call is:

`advertisementData: [String : AnyObject]`

And, when I run the code, a debug line `print("\(advertisementData)")` shows one of its values as:

> ["kCBAdvDataIsConnectable": 1, "kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs": <__NSArrayM 0x13cd812e0>(
>   C9CAB9B8-3ABF-4043-A5AF-9AD00C6074D5]

On each pass, I am trying to identify the value of the key:
 `kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs`  --  it often changes on each pass through the code

I am looking to see if the value contains:  `C9CAB9B8-3ABF-4043-A5AF-9AD00C6074D5`  (as this example does) - many times it does not.
If so I will do something. If not do nothing.

I have tried:

```
let value = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"]
```

but it did not work and the error message was not clear (at least for this newbie it wasn't clear)

How can I get this value into a variable so that I can compare it to another `String` value?

Comment: Well, what's the error message?

Answer (score 4):

This code should work

```
import CoreBluetooth

func foo(advertisementData: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let
        list = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] as? [AnyObject]
        where (list.contains { ($0 as? CBUUID)?.UUIDString == "C9CAB9B8-3ABF-4043-A5AF-9AD00C6074D5" }) {
        print("Found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Solution 1 suggestion (the Solution 2 had not been added yet).  Rather than making it a func, I put the if{ } code directly in my code. and then put a Breakpoint on the print("OK").  But, despite my debug print() code showing the presence of the 'trigger' string on a number of passes through the code, the Breakpoint at print("OK") never 'Broke'.

Comment: I just now tried Solution 2 with the Breakpoint at the  print("Found").  Unfortunately it too never "Broke" thereby indicating that the conditions were not 'found'

Comment: @Dhugalmac: Ok, could you tell me the type of the value `C9CAB9B8-3ABF-4043-A5AF-9AD00C6074D5`. Is it a `String`?

Comment: let CT_key = "c9cab9b8-3abf-4043-a5af-9ad00c6074d5".uppercaseString

Comment: @Dhugalmac: Please run this `(advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] as? [AnyObject])?.forEach { print($0, $0.dynamicType) }` and let me know what you see into the log

Comment: C9CAB9B8-3ABF-4043-A5AF-9AD00C6074D5 CBUUID:

Comment: @Dhugalmac: Please take a look at my update and don't forget the `import CoreBluetooth`

Comment: I already had the Import CoreBluetooth up higher in the code.   Regardless - HORRAY!!!  it is now working.   I am not sure I would have ever figured that one out.  THANK YOU.

Comment: @Dhugalmac: Good, don't forget to accept the answer if it does solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Updated for swift :

*use below simple code;*

```
    let yourServiceUUIDString = "FFF0"
    if let
        mAdvData = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] as? [AnyObject], (mAdvData.contains { ($0 as? CBUUID)?.uuidString == yourServiceUUIDString}) {
        print("BLE device found..!")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let value = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"]  as! [String]
let result = value.contains("C9CAB9B8-3ABF-4043-A5AF-9AD00C6074D5")
print(result ? "Found" : "Not Found")
```

Comment: You should convert that forced coercion into an `if let` or `guard`

Comment: chengsam - I tried your suggestion and it did not execute.

Comment: Can this be forced into a ```[String]```?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you could just limit your scanning results to the specific Service UUID.
Might ensure in very crowded bluetooth areas that you will not be spammed with all the others in your CBCentralManager delegate.

```
let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: "C9CAB9B8-3ABF-4043-A5AF-9AD00C6074D5")
self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
```

Or in your [CBPeripheralDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518937-centralmanager):

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                        didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                        advertisementData: [String : Any],
                        rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
    {
        print("peripheral: \(peripheral)")
        print("     \(advertisementData)")
        print (RSSI)

        if let uuids = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] as? [AnyObject],
            uuids.contains(where:{ ($0 as? CBUUID)?.uuidString == "C9CAB9B8-3ABF-4043-A5AF-9AD00C6074D5" }) {
            central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }
```